# attempting to reference a deleted function error when create a class inheriting from QGraphicsPixmapItem in QT

Tags: c++, qt

I would like to insert a picture in my scene, and do something when picture position change is detected. To realize it, I create a class BackgroundPic inheriting from QGraphicsPixmapItem. However, it arises C2280 error: 'BackgroundPic::BackgroundPic(const BackgroundPic &)': attempting to reference a deleted function (compiling source file mainwindow.cpp)     when I try to compile it. Does anyone knows what's the issue in my code?

```
#include <qstring.h>
#include <qgraphicsproxywidget.h>


class BackgroundPic: public QGraphicsPixmapItem
{
public:
    BackgroundPic()
    {
        show_flag = true;
        moveable_flag = true;
    }

    //QString name;
    float x_original;       //physical
    float y_original;
    float x;        //physical
    float y;
    QString pic_address;
    bool show_flag;
    bool moveable_flag;

    QVariant itemChange(GraphicsItemChange change, const QVariant &value)
    {
        if (change == ItemPositionChange)
        {
            x = x_original + value.toPointF().x();
            y = y_original + value.toPointF().y();
        }
        return QGraphicsItem::itemChange(change, value);
    }
};
```

Comment: `QGraphicsPixmapItem` is not copyable.

Comment: @JesperJuhl got it. I definded a vector in my mainwindow.cpp, and tried to push back BackgroundPic instance to this vector.

Comment: Which implies copying. Maybe `emplace_back` is what you want..?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem seems to be clear and it is not located in the code that you posted. In the file mainwindow.cpp there is a place where you call a copy constructor (this BackgroundPic::BackgroundPic(const BackgroundPic &)), but this function is not available.

Normaly copy constructor is defined automatically [(you can read about rule of zero and rule of five](http://www.modernescpp.com/index.php/c-core-guidelines-constructors-assignments-and-desctructors)), but in your case it is not. It happens because you inherit from a class that does not have a copy constructor. This means that your class is also not copyable.

Comment: got it. I definded a vector in my mainwindow.cpp, and tried to push back BackgroundPic instance to this vector. Maybe I should save pointer to the instance.

Comment: you can also try to use emplace_back and move the instance (C++11 required). It may happen that move constructor is still available.

Comment: one more question. Is there anything wrong with my `itemChange` function above? When I move the picture, it does trigger `itemChange` function but `if (change == ItemPositionChange && scene())` is never satisfied.

Comment: I don't know QT in such details so I am not able to help you with this one